# SPLIT a column in sql server seperated by '-'

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in my table that is composed of multiple values that are separated by `-`.

Example:

```
STB-123456789-010116
```

I want to get just:

```
col1    col2        col3
STB     123456789   010116
```

Those 3 fields will be stored in another database in 3 columns.

How can I get desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('STB-123456789-010116','-','.'),3),PARSENAME(REPLACE('STB-123456789-010116','-','.'),2),
PARSENAME(REPLACE('STB-123456789-010116','-','.'),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use `Left`, `SubString`, `Right`, `CharIndex` and `Reverse` built in [string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx):

```
DECLARE @S varchar(100) = 'STB-123456789-010116'

SELECT  LEFT(@S, CHARINDEX('-', @S) - 1) As LeftSide,
        SUBSTRING(@S, CHARINDEX('-', @S) + 1, LEN(@S) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@S)) -  CHARINDEX('-', @S)) As Middle,
        RIGHT(@S, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@S)) - 1) As RightSide




LeftSide    Middle      RightSide
---------------------------------
STB         123456789   010116
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use XML:

```
DECLARE @x xml

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  1 as id,
        'STB-123456789-010116' as some_column
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,
        'STB-9876543210-0918677'
)

SELECT @x = (
    SELECT CAST('<i id="' + CAST(id as nvarchar(10)) +'"><a>' + REPLACE(some_column,'-','</a><a>') + '</a></i>' as xml)
    FROM cte
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT  t.v.value('@id','int') as id,
        t.v.value('a[1]','nvarchar(100)') as col1,
        t.v.value('a[2]','nvarchar(100)') as col2,
        t.v.value('a[3]','nvarchar(100)') as col3
FROM @x.nodes('/i') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
id  col1    col2        col3
1   STB     123456789   010116
2   STB     9876543210  0918677
```